# RadioButtonList on ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList which contain 4 radio buttons A,B,C,D

```
RBQ.Items.Add("A")
RBQ.Items.Add("B")
RBQ.Items.Add("C")
RBQ.Items.Add("D")
```

How can set the selected value to the radio button who has the value "B"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RBC.Items.FindByValue("B").Selected = True
```

or

```
RBC.SelectedValue = 2
```

Grz, Kris.

Comment: `FindByValue` is not a member of RadioButtonList (ERROR) ?? !! %%

Comment: I can't use the second response because I don't know what will the user choose.

Comment: My bad, it's the items list bound to the radiobuttonlist, or any list control, which exposes the FindByValue method. I corrected my initial reply.

Answer (score 0):

On aspx-Page:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">B</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In Codebehind:

```
Dim item As New ListItem("A", "A")
Me.RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item)
item = New ListItem("B", "B")
item.Selected = True
Me.RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item)
item = New ListItem("C", "C")
Me.RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item)
item = New ListItem("D", "D")
Me.RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item)
```

or

```
Me.RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "B"
```